# gcc requirements to compile on OSX. Strange error message

Tags: macos, gcc

I get the following error message while trying to compile libSDL on OSX 10.6

```
/bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -g -O2  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -DTARGET_API_MAC_CARBON -DTARGET_API_MAC_OSX -fvisibility=hidden  -I/usr/X11R6/include -DXTHREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -force_cpusubtype_ALL -c ./src/audio/macosx/SDL_coreaudio.c  -o build/SDL_coreaudio.lo
libtool: compile:  gcc -g -O2 -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -DTARGET_API_MAC_CARBON -DTARGET_API_MAC_OSX -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/X11R6/include -DXTHREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -force_cpusubtype_ALL -c ./src/audio/macosx/SDL_coreaudio.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_coreaudio.o
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardware.h:83,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/CoreAudio.h:19,
                 from ./src/audio/macosx/SDL_coreaudio.c:24:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBundle.h:147: 
                      error: format string argument not a string type
make: *** [build/SDL_coreaudio.lo] Error 1
```

According to the [following post on FLTK mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/fltk@easysw.com/msg08332.html) the problem is due to the fact that I am not using Apple provided gcc. Indeed I am using my own compiler

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.3.4
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Which is different from the Apple provided gcc:

```
/usr/bin/gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What I am curious about is the difference between the two... Of course I don't expect you to know what's going on in my compiler, but I would expect someone knows what's special in the Apple gcc so that the error does not arise.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's GCC has been extended to understand that `CFString` is a string type that can be used with `__attribute__((format_arg(...)))` (which is used to provide some extra error-checking when format strings are passed between functions).  There is a conditional in the header which tries to disable this usage of the attribute if the compiler doesn't support it, but it fails to check for Apple-specific GCC.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44981 - it looks like it has now been implemented in mainline GCC.